# PhpMyAdmin - I see only PHP code in the browser

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried installing PHPMyAdmin in my local system. When started, it only shows the PHP code in the browser as you can see:

[image: Browser Output]

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Apache2 PHP module. Use the command below

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php

and restart your apache server. Use the command below for restarting your apache server

> sudo service apache2 restart

hope it helps